# How to save the result from JDBC query into a variable?

Tags: java

in java.How to save a result of a sql query into a variable?

```
        java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        String query = "select season from seasonTable where league_name=?";

        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, league);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

I need to save the retrieved season into a variable how can I do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `rs.next()` to move the cursor for the ResultSet to the next row. That method will return a boolean indicating whether or not there actually **is** a next row, so you can use either an `if` statement or a `while` loop to retrieve the first or all of the rows returned.

```
// only ever retrieve the value from the first returned row, even if there are multiple
String season = null;
if(rs.next())
    season = rs.getString(1);
```

OR

```
// retrieve the values of all returned rows and store them in a list
List<String> seasons = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next())
    seasons.add(rs.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the ResultSet, and get the suitable column. e.g.

```
String season = null;
while (rs.next()) {
   season = rs.getString(column_name); // you can use column name or index
}
```

Note that you may wish to check for only one entry in the `ResultSet`, and/or that `season` gets populated. On the other hand you may want to record multiple seasons, hence:

```
List<String> seasons = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
   seasons.add(rs.getString(column_name)); 
}
```

I would prefer to get the column *by name* rather than by index. That way you can change your query (to some degree) and the dereferencing will still work.

[Here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/getrsdata.html) are some more examples.

Comment: That will overwrite the variable once and again for each iteration.

Comment: Yes it will. Hence my comment about checking for *one* entry only.

Answer (score 0):

```
String season = null;
if (rs.next()) {
    season = rs.getString(1);
}
```

Read the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) you will see you there are methods to access the columns from the ResultSet using either their index or their name. For each type to retrieve there is a method : `getString()`, `getFloat()` etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s;
// Fetch each row from the result set
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Get the data from the row using the column index
            s = rs.getString(1);
                     /**    OR   **/
            // Get the data from the row using the column name
            s = rs.getString("season");
        }
```